# How to skip the phase in JSF application?

Tags: jsf

HI,

I am looking for a scenario where I can skip some of the phases in the life cycle. I have seen code for skipping those. But, I have serious doubt about where actually I can write that logic.

Is it in the ManagedBean or PhaseListener?

Looking for the answer.

Comment: why do you want to skip phases?

Comment: Just want to know if there is any way to do this? Maybe to render it fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `immediate=true` to your action component ["skips" a phase](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/How_The_Immediate_Attribute_Works). You can't do more than that.

> Many developers are under the impression that using the immediate flag on a component skips the "Process Validations" phase. It doesn't. What using immediate does is cause a component to be processed in the Apply Request Values phase.

Comment: Your answer is talking about the immediate attribute. How can I skip some of the phases and directly move to the RenderResponse phase?

Comment: As he mentioned, you can't skip phases. But I am curious Why do you want to do this!

Comment: I am able to skip the phases in PhaseListener. But, there is no use of it. If we give FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse(), it directly takes to the final phase. Again it is not useful. I am just curious to know what is it possible? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hi Bozho, Thank you for the answer. I am reading the immediate attribute.

Comment: In the document it mentioned as "Using immediate means the component value will be validated during apply-request-values, ie before any non-immediate component values (which validate in process-validations)". What is the advantage of validating one phase earlier?

Answer (score 2):

FacesContext has a method [responseComplete()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29) which marks the response as complete. It also has [renderResponse()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) to jump to the Render Response phase.

I'm trying to use these during the Before Restore View phase and having trouble. After Restore View and beyond they seem fine.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to have access to the `FacesContext` on a custom request handler for GAE task queue.  The task is created by building a post request and I had no idea how to create the `ViewState` parameter.  I am using `FacesContext.responseComplete()` as suggested by Richard in a `PhaseListener`.  I needed to skip the rest of the phases because the URL does not map to any file and I am doing all the work in the listener anyway.

```
public class TaskPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
        if ("/taskUrl".equals(context.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo())) {
            Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext()
               .getRequestParameterMap();
            // do the task here and skip the rest of the phases
            context.responseComplete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        // only interested in first phase
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }

}
```

I am sure there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach, so please comment.